# Using mpl::transform to generate a new sequence

Tags: c++, boost-mpl

I am trying to generate some generic configuration handling code that maps indexes to types, using a `fusion::map` with an internal format as follows:

```
fusion::pair< mpl::int_< VALUE >, type >;
```

To simplify generation of the map I have the following code:

```
#include <boost/fusion/sequence.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/container.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/algorithm.hpp>

#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/map.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_const.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_reference.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>

#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

/// create a fusion map of all parameter data
namespace fusion = boost::fusion;
namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

template < unsigned Idx, typename T >
struct config_param
{
    typedef mpl::int_< Idx > index_value;
    typedef T value_type;
};

template< class T >
struct to_fusion_pair
{
    typedef fusion::pair< typename T::index_value
                        , typename T::value_type > type;
};

typedef mpl::vector< config_param< 10, unsigned >
                   , config_param< 20, std::string >
                   , config_param< 30, bool >
                   , config_param< 40, long >
                   , config_param< 50, std::string >
                   > MySequence;

typedef mpl::transform< MySequence, to_fusion_pair< mpl::_1 > >::type ConvertedSeq;
```

This compiles and produces the expected results, unfortunately if I try to wrap the call  to transform, I get a large number of errors. i.e:

```
template< class Seq >
struct to_vector_of_fusion_pair
{
    typedef mpl::transform< Seq, to_fusion_pair< mpl::_1 > >::type type;
};

typedef to_vector_of_fusion_pair<MySequence>::type ConvertedSeq2;
```

The compiler errors are as follows:

```
fusion-db.cpp:40: error: type boost::mpl::transform<Seq, to_fusion_pair<mpl_::arg<1> >, mpl_::na, mpl_::na> is not derived from type to_vector_of_fusion_pair<Seq>â
fusion-db.cpp:40: error: expected ; before type
```

What is wrong with my `to_vector_of_fusion_pair` structure that makes it incompatible with `mpl::transform`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template< class Seq >
struct to_vector_of_fusion_pair
{
    typedef typename mpl::transform< Seq, to_fusion_pair< mpl::_1 > >::type type;
};
```

Read this for explanations [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)